# Maharsha on Shas - Standalone Edition

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, maharsha

Can anyone recommend standalone editions of the Maharsha's commentary on Shas? I am looking for ones with clear print, in all-Hebrew.

Comment: Of interest https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20940&st=&pgnum=42&hilite=

Comment: It is important to note that the author stipulated in his introduction that whenever his book shall be published it must contain both sections of his writings otherwise it is forbidden to publish. Fun fact

Comment: Why do you want this? What's wrong with the edition in back of ubiquitous talmudim?

Comment: @DoubleAA perhaps he is using an old vilna offset

Comment: @DrShmu ...and has no access or interest to find any new edition

Comment: It's not in the back of my Shas. I own the Koren all-Hebrew Vilna-Steinsaltz Edition. The commentary by R. Steinsaltz is amazing, but the commentary by the Maharsha is not found in the back.

Comment: @Bs234570 Do you learn maharsha so often that you can't check a reference volume at a shul or something? Is it not worth investing in a standard shas with its dozens of commentaries instead of buying all these sets piecemeal? Your responses to me are woefully insufficient to justify this.

Answer (score 2):

The only one I have ever seen is Maharsha HeAruch. Each Masechta is its own volume, with a lot of commentary on the page. But it's very useful if you want help with Maharsha.

Comment: Do you know where I can find that title?

Comment: https://www.lehmanns.co.uk/mhrw-a-harvk-st-el-hw-s-v-krkim.html

Comment: https://www.lehmanns.co.uk/catalogsearch/result/?q=%D7%9E%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%A9%22%D7%90+%D7%94%D7%90%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A